# Datapicker filter is not working

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am trying to filter by date using a Datapicker.
I inserted the input form in the table head and i have an input form only for date. When i click on  the form, it appears the calendar to choose a date, but when i click the date it does not show results for that date.

I am also  using datatables.

This is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $('#example thead th').not(":eq(0),:eq(2),:eq(3),:eq(4),:eq(5),:eq(6),:eq(7),:eq(8),:eq(9),:eq(10)").each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title === "Date") 
        {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching":false,
        });
        $('#example tbody')
           .on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
               var colIdx = table.cell(this).index().column;
               $(table.cells().nodes()).removeClass('highlight');
               $(table.column(colIdx).nodes()).addClass('highlight');
           });

        table.columns().every(function () {
            var that = this;
            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

What should i do to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: is there only one datepicker?

Comment: Yes,it is only one datapicker.